# Intellij horizontal scroll for NPM console or disable word wrapping

Tags: intellij-idea

Anyone have idea how to turn on a horizontall scroll or disable work wrapping?

[image]

Comment: Why scroll when there are no long lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way; **NPM** tool window uses the embedded terminal as console (as, unlike the standard IDE console, it allows running node without input/output streams redirection and thus supports TTY mode). And there is currently no way to disable lines wrapping in terminal ([IDEA-212620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212620))